# Loading Data From External File in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bigcommerce

I am probably missing something minuscule here, but I'm sure an extra set of eyes (or someone more expeireinced with JQuery) will be the answer to this.

Our shopping cart is hosted by BigCommerce, and sometimes we need to come up with work arounds in order for things that should be standard out of the box, implemented. So on our category pages (example here: http://www.contourliving.com/pillows/ ), the little short descriptions that are loaded into every listing are called by using a jquery script similar to this:

```
$("#this_div_is_called_on_cat_page).load("path_to_external_file #div");
```

And if you look at the category page, it seems to work, however there are the occasional products that are not working as expected. Even though the divs in are external file, they are just not getting loaded.

So my question to this mystery is, why would this be occurring? What am I missing here? Listed below is a link to my external file (as Im thinking that is where it has to be going wrong);

http://deals.contourliving.com/template/Snippets/CategoryProductSummary.html

Thanks in advance,
Kate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a callback function to your `load()` calls, then use your web browser's Javascript console to inspect the results. This should help you understand what's going wrong. Here's an example:

```
$("#prod_summary_377").load("http://your-website.com/template/Snippets/CategoryProductSummary.html #377", function(response, status, xhr){
  console.log(status);
  if (status == "error") {
    console.log(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

See the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for more information.

Also, your `CategoryProductSummary.html` page contains 2 `div` elements with the same ID: `<div id="337">`, so try fixing that.

Comment: Thanks so much Mark, that is really helpful. I went to add it to the function in the site files, and because I originally set this up on our dev site, so it was actually referencing the dev site path to the summary.html page. They are absolutely correct when they say, sometimes you just need to walk away from it for awhile. Thanks so much again - without you I would of never caught that!